Is there any Graph API which give session timeout for organization in M365?
I am trying to get Session timeout by Graph API but didn't find any api for that.
We are trying to retrieve the session timeout setting via graph API , is there any API which will give the session timeout set for the organization in M365. Response should have session timeout is enabled or not , if yes the what is the timeout.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
